# How to convert to stat_summary_2d?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using 'flights' data set from 'nycflights13' package. I was required to convert to code containing 'stat_summary_2d' from the original code:

```
    flights %>%
  mutate(cancel = 1*(dep_time %>% is.na)) %>%
  group_by(carrier, origin) %>%
  summarise(cancel = 100*mean(cancel, na.rm = T)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_tile(aes(origin, carrier, fill = cancel)) +
  geom_text(aes(origin, carrier, label = round(cancel,1)),
            col = "blue", size = 5) +
  scale_fill_distiller("Cancel Ratio", palette = "RdYlGn") +
  theme_bw()
```

In the data set the missing value of the 'dep_time' variable means a cancelled flight, and the variable 'cancel' is created by calculating the  proportion of cancelled flights over the scheduled flights.
Below is how I apply 'stat_summary_2d' to convert the original code:

```
    flights %>%
  mutate(cancel = 1*(dep_time %>% is.na)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  stat_summary_2d(aes(carrier, origin, z = cancel)) +
  geom_text(data = flights %>% group_by(carrier, origin) %>%
              summarize(cancel = 100*mean(cancel, na.rm = T)) %>% ungroup,
            aes(factor(carrier), origin, label = round(cancel,1)),
            col = "blue", size = 5) +
  scale_fill_distiller("Cancel Ratio", palette = "RdYlGn") +
  theme_bw()
```

When I execute my code, the error is

> ```
> > Error in summarize()`: ! Problem while computing `cancel = 100 *
> > mean(cancel, na.rm = T)`. i The error occurred in group 1: carrier =
> > "9E", origin = "EWR".
> ```

Could anyone tell me how to fix this problem? Thank you so much!

Comment: You are using a dataset with no `cancel` created

Comment: I already used `mutate`   to create `cancel` but still have no idea why error still exists

Comment: Yes, but the `mutate` is not updating the `flights` object unless you do `flights<- flights %>%   mutate(cancel = 1*(dep_time %>% is.na))`   In the second `data`, you are still using the orignal `flights` object

Comment: THere are ways to get the original object updated in theloop i.e. with `%<>%` instead of `%>%`, but I would suggest to use a more clean, bug free approach

Answer (score 0):

The original data is not updated when with the new column unless we use `%<>%` instead of `%>%`.  But, it may be easier to create two objects

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
flight1 <- flights %>%
   mutate(cancel = 1*(dep_time %>% is.na))
 flight2 <- flights1 %>%
   group_by(carrier, origin) %>%
   summarize(cancel = 100*mean(cancel, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
ggplot(flight1) + 
  stat_summary_2d(aes(carrier, origin, z = cancel)) + 
 geom_text(data = flight2, aes(factor(carrier),
  origin, label = round(cancel,1)),
             col = "blue", size = 5) +
   scale_fill_distiller("Cancel Ratio", palette = "RdYlGn") +
   theme_bw()
```